# ngram text to be as separate column in R

Tags: r, n-gram

I got list of several text got from ngram, and want to add to original datatable as columns.

```
> prep_test
                                                                                          prep_test
 1:                      Women Athletic,Athletic Apparel,Apparel Pants,Pants Tights,Tights Leggings
 2:                                                                       Beauty Makeup,Makeup Face
 3:                                                                       Beauty Makeup,Makeup Face
 4:     Electronics Cell,Cell Phones,Phones Accessories,Accessories Cases,Cases Covers,Covers Skins
 5:                                                                         Women Shoes,Shoes Boots
 6:                                                   Men Men,Men s,s Accessories,Accessories Belts
 7: Electronics Cell,Cell Phones,Phones Accessories,Accessories Cell,Cell Phones,Phones Smartphones
 8:                                                           Women Tops,Tops Blouses,Blouses Other
 9:                      Women Athletic,Athletic Apparel,Apparel Pants,Pants Tights,Tights Leggings
10:                                                Home Home,Home DÃ,DÃ cor,cor Home,Home Fragrance



str(prep_test)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ prep_test:List of 10
  ..$ : chr  "Women Athletic" "Athletic Apparel" "Apparel Pants" "Pants Tights" ...
  ..$ : chr  "Beauty Makeup" "Makeup Face"
  ..$ : chr  "Beauty Makeup" "Makeup Face"
  ..$ : chr  "Electronics Cell" "Cell Phones" "Phones Accessories" "Accessories Cases" ...
  ..$ : chr  "Women Shoes" "Shoes Boots"
  ..$ : chr  "Men Men" "Men s" "s Accessories" "Accessories Belts"
  ..$ : chr  "Electronics Cell" "Cell Phones" "Phones Accessories" "Accessories Cell" ...
  ..$ : chr  "Women Tops" "Tops Blouses" "Blouses Other"
  ..$ : chr  "Women Athletic" "Athletic Apparel" "Apparel Pants" "Pants Tights" ...
  ..$ : chr  "Home Home" "Home DÃ" "DÃ cor" "cor Home" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

current code to generate n-gram for a column

```
bigram_fun <- function(y){
  y <- gsub("[[:punct:][:blank:]]+", " ", y)
  y <- ngram_asweka(y, min=2, max=2)
  #y <- str_split_fixed(y, ",", n=Inf)
  #y <- unlist(y)
  return(y)
}

prep_test <- all[1:10, 9]
prep_test <- apply(prep_test, 1, bigram_fun)
prep_test <- data.table(prep_test)
prep_test
```

dput here

```
> dput(prep_test)
list(c("Women Athletic", "Athletic Apparel", "Apparel Pants", 
"Pants Tights", "Tights Leggings"), c("Beauty Makeup", "Makeup Face"
), c("Beauty Makeup", "Makeup Face"), c("Electronics Cell", "Cell Phones", 
"Phones Accessories", "Accessories Cases", "Cases Covers", "Covers Skins"
), c("Women Shoes", "Shoes Boots"), c("Men Men", "Men s", "s Accessories", 
"Accessories Belts"), c("Electronics Cell", "Cell Phones", "Phones Accessories", 
"Accessories Cell", "Cell Phones", "Phones Smartphones"), c("Women Tops", 
"Tops Blouses", "Blouses Other"), c("Women Athletic", "Athletic Apparel", 
"Apparel Pants", "Pants Tights", "Tights Leggings"), c("Home Home", 
"Home DÃ", "DÃ cor", "cor Home", "Home Fragrance"))
```

desired outcome

```
Bigram 1           Bigram 2           Bigram 3              Bigram 4     ...  
"Women Athletic"   "Athletic Apparel" "Apparel Pants"      "Pants Tights"...
"Beauty Makeup"    "Makeup Face"      NA                    NA           ...
"Beauty Makeup"    "Makeup Face"      NA                    NA           ...
"Electronics Cell" "Cell Phones"      "Phones Accessories" "Accessories Cases" 
"Women Shoes"      "Shoes Boots"      NA                    NA
```

Appreciate any answers, and sorry for poor questions here as a newbie here

Comment: upload `dput` of your data so that any of your code is reproducible

Comment: `prep_test` is a data.table object in your question. But your `dput` contains a list, not a data table. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(plyr)
df = rbind.fill(lapply(mylist,function(x) {as.data.frame(t(x))}))
colnames(df) = sapply(seq(1:ncol(df)),function(x) {paste0("Bigram ",x)})
```

Output:

```
           Bigram 1         Bigram 2           Bigram 3          Bigram 4        Bigram 5           Bigram 6
1    Women Athletic Athletic Apparel      Apparel Pants      Pants Tights Tights Leggings               <NA>
2     Beauty Makeup      Makeup Face               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
3     Beauty Makeup      Makeup Face               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
4  Electronics Cell      Cell Phones Phones Accessories Accessories Cases    Cases Covers       Covers Skins
5       Women Shoes      Shoes Boots               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
6           Men Men            Men s      s Accessories Accessories Belts            <NA>               <NA>
7  Electronics Cell      Cell Phones Phones Accessories  Accessories Cell     Cell Phones Phones Smartphones
8        Women Tops     Tops Blouses      Blouses Other              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
9    Women Athletic Athletic Apparel      Apparel Pants      Pants Tights Tights Leggings               <NA>
10        Home Home          Home DÃ             DÃ cor          cor Home  Home Fragrance               <NA>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the bigrams to data frames, bind into a molten data frame, then cast to a wide format tidy data file as follows.

```
theBigrams <- list(c("Women Athletic", "Athletic Apparel", "Apparel Pants", 
"Pants Tights", "Tights Leggings"), c("Beauty Makeup", "Makeup Face"),
 c("Beauty Makeup", "Makeup Face"), c("Electronics Cell", "Cell Phones", 
"Phones Accessories", "Accessories Cases", "Cases Covers", "Covers Skins"
), c("Women Shoes", "Shoes Boots"), c("Men Men", "Men s", "s Accessories", 
"Accessories Belts"), c("Electronics Cell", "Cell Phones", "Phones Accessories", 
"Accessories Cell", "Cell Phones", "Phones Smartphones"), c("Women Tops", 
"Tops Blouses", "Blouses Other"), c("Women Athletic", "Athletic Apparel", 
"Apparel Pants", "Pants Tights", "Tights Leggings"), c("Home Home", 
"Home DÃ", "DÃ cor", "cor Home", "Home Fragrance"))

meltedBigrams <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(theBigrams),function(i) {
     x <- theBigrams[[i]]
     bigram <- 1:length(x)
     id <- rep(i,length(x))
     data.frame(id,bigram,value=x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}))
library(reshape2)
castData <- dcast(meltedBigrams,id ~ bigram )
castData
```

...and the output:

```
> castData
   id                1                2                  3                 4               5                  6
1   1   Women Athletic Athletic Apparel      Apparel Pants      Pants Tights Tights Leggings               <NA>
2   2    Beauty Makeup      Makeup Face               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
3   3    Beauty Makeup      Makeup Face               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
4   4 Electronics Cell      Cell Phones Phones Accessories Accessories Cases    Cases Covers       Covers Skins
5   5      Women Shoes      Shoes Boots               <NA>              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
6   6          Men Men            Men s      s Accessories Accessories Belts            <NA>               <NA>
7   7 Electronics Cell      Cell Phones Phones Accessories  Accessories Cell     Cell Phones Phones Smartphones
8   8       Women Tops     Tops Blouses      Blouses Other              <NA>            <NA>               <NA>
9   9   Women Athletic Athletic Apparel      Apparel Pants      Pants Tights Tights Leggings               <NA>
10 10        Home Home          Home DÃ             DÃ cor          cor Home  Home Fragrance               <NA>
>
```